# Use modem on Guest VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization

Is there a way where i can use my PCI modem in a virtual machine on an ubuntu 12.04 host box?
I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the host and i want to use my PCI modem on a guess virtual machine. 
Can this be done using kvm, vmware or virtualbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't usually, except under very specific circumstances - which may or may not apply to you. The term you are looking for is PCI passthrough, and that requires a VM host that supports it *and* a processor with VT-D/IOMMU. You've not mentioned your host, but I've covered xen, VMware workstation and esxi (though the latter is irrelevant to you) and virtualbox

You can do USB passthrough, but I can't think of any VM host that does PCI passthrough, and very few (mostly hypervisor OSes like ESX) that do PCIe passthrough. PCI and PCIe require lower level access to a system, and in the case of PCIe passthrough, this means direct memory access for the VM using VT-D/IOMMU.

Here's [an example](https://serverfault.com/questions/482383/how-can-i-setup-pci-passthrough-for-my-highpoint-1144a-usb-3-0-card-under-esxi-5/543717) of someone trying (and having trouble with) a PCIe card with esxi - and as you can see its not simple

Xen seems to have support for [pci passthrough](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_PCI_Passthrough), but once again, this needs VT-D/IOMMU, and I believe patched kernels.

I've not heard of anyone doing PCI passthrough on virtualbox or vmware workstation.

Considering all this, it may be simpler to run the modem on the host, and use NAT on the guest to network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With VMWare and VB I have been able to route serial traffic from the VM to my modem in the past. There should be lots of HOWTOs out there. I would link one, but rumor has it's sort of a no no on here =). Just make sure nothing outside of the VM has it busy.

Comment: I there any technical keywords to make my search? i can't find any with the idea i currently have...

Comment: something like this should get you going: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16586/how-to-access-serial-ubuntu-host-serial-port-on-virtualbox-guest-os. Maybe I'm in the wrong ballpark